# In a nutshell, how can a friendship become a tragedy?

Tags: technique, planning

The narrator is called Karl who is a sixteen year old pupil at a boarding school. During a summer Sports Day with a rival school, he meets one of the pupils who is both a nuisance and is adorable (and is a boy his age)

Where do I go from here to use this friendship to spice up the storyline?

(There are other storylines in this story but they too aren't fully developed)

Comment: I am not sure your title and your question are really related... can you develop the question some or change the title?

Comment: I agree with Erik, the title and the question are unrelated. Please elaborate further

Comment: To be unoriginal the new friend can have the proverbial "deep dark secret."

Comment: Questions asking what to write are off-topic here. Placed on hold for now, but editing this to ask about specific techniques or writing tools would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you're after. Here are a few examples that come to mind:

1. Karl quietly befriends boy, boy is mocked or teased by others, boy is significantly injured or killed as a result of bullying or self-harming, and Karl carries the weight of having done nothing.
2. Karl befriends boy, is jealous of boy because of confidence or other issues, doesn't trust boy, and thus Karl does something that results in harm/pain for someone else. Karl is deeply guilty.

Essentially you have to bring them close, establish that they are close, and then have the reason why a split happens. Making it a tragedy means that there has to be some large emotional event, e.g. a death, something burns down, someone is significantly harmed such that it changes them, etc. This can either result by explicit action (like in #2 above) or through inaction (like in #1).

I'm guessing you're looking at using this as backstory. However, if you aren't, it sounds like you aren't planning to have this as an over-arching element of the story. Careful not to overwhelm your story with it.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

"In a nutshell," **Romeo and Juliet** was the "classic" story along this line.

Admittedly, that was a "boy-girl" story, but you could have an "all boy" story along similar lines.

The two schools are "rivals" after all. If there was a plot development that made them "hate" each other, that would create the conflict you want.